# any way to customise ajaxfileupload from ajax control toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have downloaded ajax control toolkit (newest) and trying out fileupload.

It's really good and I would like to customise a few things such as the button positions and upload file list position etc.

Is there any way to customise this?

All I can think of is using javascript after the event to move the element from on container(either div, span, table) to the other.

Any help will be much much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answers guys.
What I actually did is downloading the source file with the full solution and modifying the actual code.
[source code link](http://fileuploadajax.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

It has lots of Javascript to play around with so it's a bit tricky.

Anyway this will give you a bit more of freedom placing the controls etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with **javascript**:

- [Quick example client side](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brettrobinson/archive/2008/02/28/override-javascript-method-in-microsoft-ajax-library.aspx)
- [Quick example server side](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37543/How-to-Customize-the-New-AjaxControlToolkit-Tools)

Override the events you care about then move the element you want with jQuery if you wanted:
`$('#currentElem').prependTo('#destElem');`

You could also do this with **CSS only**:

```
.ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam, could you explain how this applies to the ajaxuploadcontrol? 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx 
this is example on the asp.net website.
Thanks!

Comment: @rlee923 I've updated my answer to hopefully clear up some of the ambiguity.  I prefer CSS only myself in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can customise this control with css, just mark the css with !important setences, this will work for you. Use Firebug to know the css class.

example

```
.ajax__fileupload_dropzone 
{
    border:dotted 1px #B2D1E0 !important;
    color:#B2D1E0 !important;
}
```